# C math lib - float miscalculations?

Tags: c, math, floating-point

I am aware of floating points in C not being very precise. But I have a sniplet where I do not understand why I am getting such results.
First, if I do the calculate within one line I am getting a wrong "0" as result.
Just if I split the same calculations into several commands I am getting nearly what I would expect.

So first questions:

1. Why is the single line different from the split lines?
2. Is there any way how to calculate in a more precise way? I mean, 320-(10.44*4) should be 278.24 and not 278.23999! I understand rounding issues at number like roots or pi or so. But not in above example.

Ok, here is my code (minimized sniplet):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float kurv_steil,
        kurv_korr,
        t_abl_s,
        t_out,
        t_abl_s,
        b,
        t_tank_s;

void main()
{
    t_tank_s=32;
    kurv_steil=0.85;
    kurv_korr=-5;
    t_out=1.44;
    t_abl_s=24;

    printf("Werte: k_steil: %f k_korr: %f t_out: %f t_abl_s: %f\n",kurv_steil,kurv_korr,t_out,t_abl_s);
    b= pow(t_abl_s,(t_out/(320-(t_out*4) )))*0.65*kurv_steil*b*(-t_out+20);

    printf("[temp] Ganze Rechnung tank_s: %f\n",b);
    b=320-(t_out*4);

    printf("[temp] 320-(t_out*4) b: %f\n",b);
    b=t_out/b;

    printf("[temp] t_out/b b: %f\n",b);
    b=pow(t_abl_s,b);

    printf("[temp] t_abl_s^b b: %f\n",b);
    b=0.65*kurv_steil*b;

    printf("[temp] 0.65*kurv_steil*b b: %f\n",b);
    b=b*(-t_out+20);

    printf("[temp] b*(-t_out+20) b: %f\n",b);
    b=2*b+t_abl_s+kurv_korr;

    printf("[temp] 2*b*(-t_abl_s) b: %f\n",b);
}
```

Output is:

```
Werte: k_steil: 0.850000 k_korr: -5.000000 t_out: 1.440000 t_abl_s: 24.000000
[temp] Ganze Rechnung tank_s: 0.000000
[temp] 320-(t_out*4) b: 314.239990
[temp] t_out/b b: 0.004582
[temp] t_abl_s^b b: 1.014670
[temp] 0.65*kurv_steil*b b: 0.560605
[temp] b*(-t_out+20) b: 10.404831
[temp] 2*b*(-t_abl_s) b: 39.809662
```

I would expect to have the first output have the same value of "39.809662", but it always has "0". Why?

Comment: Indent your code before to post and write it in English so people can understand something more.

Comment: Signature for main can be: `int main (void)` or `main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: A simple thing you can do is change the formatting for printing numbers rather that `%f` try using `%.3f` or `%6.3f`. Maths in C is very accurate is more that the results don't always appear nicely in decimals.

Comment: You said you understand that floating point is not exact and then you say that  278.24 is not 278.23999. For 32bit float this is fine. And the order in which you calculate your result strongly impacts the result

Comment: The difference between 278.24 and 278.23999 is 0.00001. Assume you measured the length of a field in meters, the error would be a thousandth of a millimeter, or 10 microns. Or if your fortune amounts to $278,240,000, will you care about $10 ? I cannot call that "no very precise".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as told above the problem is in formula you use. You have `b=... *b*...`. The `b` has unknown value by this moment (most likely compiler set it to 0) so you have `b=...*0*...` which makes end result has 0 value.

Also you should add `2* ... + t_abl_s+kurv_korr` to your formula

So the formula will looks like

```
b= 2 *
   pow(t_abl_s,(t_out/(320-(t_out*4) ))) *
   0.65 * kurv_steil *
   (-t_out+20) +
   t_abl_s + kurv_korr;
```

Answer (score 4):

In this line

```
b= pow(t_abl_s,(t_out/(320-(t_out*4) )))*0.65*kurv_steil*  b  *(-t_out+20);
```

you are using the variable b on the right-hand side. This will typically be zero when the program starts, so anything multiplied by it will be zero. Don't rely on any variable having a specific value, always initialise your variables.

Comment: Since when is it typically zero? It is undefined and I would assume it is not zero more often than it is. Solid answer, it just sounds so trivial while its a grave mistake.

Comment: @KamiKaze In this case the variable is declared at file scope, meaning it has static storage duration and is therefore always zero. Guaranteed by the C standard, so the answer is correct, apart from the "typically" - it _will_ be zero. Still, it is bad practice to write programs that rely on zero-initialization of static storage duration variables.

Comment: @Lundin The clarification is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this link, 1.44 cannot be represented in binary:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.44+in+binary

So any floating point computations you do with it will be imprecise.

A more familiar example is to try to represent 1/3.  In base3, it's simply 0.1.   In decimal, it's 0.33333...   It's the same idea with any decimal number ending in .44.   It cannot be precisely represented in binary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!

Oh man! I was so stupid. Yes, indeed there was a "*b" in the formula which resulted in being "0" all time as b was not initialized before (and obviously by random always zero).

Regarding the precision of the calculation I am not convinced as 278.24 is not the same as 278.23999. On the other side, it works for me now.

Thanks!

Comment: As soon as you use floating point you are bound to have errors in it. It's your duty to keep them low. Because of this you don't compare float with ==. For example try 0.1+0.1+0.1 == 0.3 this should be false.